# Multiplying non-zeros values of two matrices

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices multiplied with each other *H.Z* where both matrices *H* and *Z* have the same size of *(256,256)*. Matrix *Z* is permutation matrix has the following pattern: In the first *32* rows, only columns *1,9,17,...(256-8)* are non-zeros, other columns are zeros,  next *32* rows, only columns *2,10,18,...(256-7)* are non-zeros, other columns are zeros and so on till the last *32* rows, where columns *8,16,24,....,256* are non-zeros and other columns are zeros.

Therefore, multiplying matrix *H* with *Z* includes only multiplying the first *32* elements of first row in *H* with the first *32* element of column 1 of matrix *Z*, then next 32 element of first rows of matrix *H* with next *32* element  (*33-64* elements) of column *2* in matrix *Z* and so on. because all other multiplications will result of zero. So in that way, the number of multiplication will be less.

My question, I couldn't write that in Matlab !! I don't know how create the loop to go through only the non-zeros elements. Could you please help in that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Just use normal element wise multiplication for all the elements. Looping through only non zero entries is much less efficient

Comment: @SardarUsama thank you for your reply.  Yes, that's what I need to do ? looping through non zeros entries of *Z*.  How can I do that ?

Comment: "Therefore, multiplying matrix H with Z includes only"... so you are saying H*Z would result in the correct result, but you are trying to skip the nzero ones?

Comment: you can get the slices with non-zero elements by `find(any(M,2))`, where the `2` determines the direction, i.e. if it is columns or rows

Comment: @Daniel Yes, exactly ... that's what I mean

Comment: you could also transform your `H` and `Z` matrix to sparse matrix, but it will slow down the computation.

Comment: @obchardon Thanks for your reply. How can I do that ? could you please explain that.

Comment: `sparse(H)*sparse(Z)`, a sparse matrix store only the non zero value, but again sparse matrix multiplication are way slower than classical matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loops are generally much slower than inbuilt MATLAB operations. A better options is to multiply only the nonzero elements of `Z` using the following approach.

```matlab
result = zeros(256,256);
result(Z ~= 0) = H(Z ~= 0) .* Z(Z ~= 0);
```

You can see the complete code below, running a test to make sure it gets the right answer, and timing the code to see if it's faster.

```matlab
% setup variables
H = rand(256,256);
Z = zeros(256,256);
for i = 1:8
    Z((i-1)*32+1:i*32, i:8:256) = 1;
end

% run calcuations and check that they are equal
HZ1 = f1(H, Z);
HZ2 = f2(H, Z);
are_equal = all(all(HZ1 == HZ2));

% time both functions
timeit(@() f1(H,Z))
timeit(@() f2(H,Z))

function result = f1(H, Z)
    result = H .* Z;
end
function result = f2(H, Z)
    result = zeros(256,256);
    result(Z ~= 0) = H(Z ~= 0) .* Z(Z ~= 0);
end
```

Timeit results:

```
f1 - 6.875835e-05 s
f2 - 0.0008205853 s
```

Unfortunately, the new approach is about 12 times slower than just multiplying the matrices elementwise. This is because MATLAB is heavily optimised for matrix multiplication, and multiplying the complete matrices `H` and `Z` ensures the memory to be operated on is contiguous.